# Can I publish enterprise app as free app in Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play, enterprise

Can I publish enterprise app as free app in Google Play store? I developed an application for my clients. Only the registered users (from my portal ) can only login into this application. We are charging the users for registration from portal side. So can I publish this app as free app in play store, so it can available to my clients to download from play store instead from my private app store.

Comment: Yes actually, I've seen several companies do it.

Comment: @GianPatrick - Thanks for your replay, but I just want to know that is this legal or not in terms of google's https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

Answer (score 0):

This should be okay. I once downloaded Nikkei News APP but it is only intended to be used by registered users. I have to uninstall it right after the first try.